# Is this BST validation function correct?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I've written some logic for validating a BST which seems to work:

```py
class Node:
  val: int
  left: 'Node | None' = None
  right: 'Node | None' = None

  def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
    self.val = val
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

# -----------------------

def isValidBST(root: Node, mn=float('-Inf'), mx=float('+Inf')) -> bool:
  if not (mn < root.val < mx):
    return False
  if root.left and not isValidBST(root.left, mn=mn, mx=root.val):
    return False
  if root.right and not isValidBST(root.right, mn=root.val, mx=mx):
    return False
  return True
```

I've tried testing it against this tree definition:

```py
#          5
#     2         9
#   0   4     7   10 
#           6

tree = Node(5,
            Node(2,
                 Node(0),
                 Node(4)),
            Node(9,
                 Node(7,
                      Node(6)),
                 Node(10)))
```

The function returns `True`. If I make the tree invalid (like by switching 4 to 5 or 7 to 3), it returns `False`. It also seems to stop at the right time, which I checked with some logs.

Is this function valid? Could it be made better somehow either way?

Comment: I strongly encourage you to add `left` and `right` optional arguments to `__init__`, so that you can build a tree in one line with `tree = Node(5, Node(2, Node(0), Node(4)), Node(9, Node(7, Node(6), Node()), Node(10)))`

Comment: @Stef yes I had them initially, just personally felt awkward defining the tree that way so I removed them

Comment: If it's the "one line" aspect that troubles you, you can add new lines. I can't add new lines inside a comment, but replace `/` with a new line and this would work: `tree = Node(5,/
            Node(2,/
                 Node(0),/
                 Node(4)),/
            Node(9,/
                 Node(7,/
                      Node(6),/
                      Node()),/
                 Node(10)))`

Comment: @Stef did it now. Is the function itself good though?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct and clear. There's only one very small improvement you can make, instead of -Inf and +Inf you could use -inf and inf, like this:

```py
class Node:
  val: int
  left: 'Node | None' = None
  right: 'Node | None' = None

  def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
    self.val = val
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

# -----------------------

def isValidBST(root: Node, mn=float('-inf'), mx=float('inf')) -> bool:
  if not (mn < root.val < mx):
    return False
  if root.left and not isValidBST(root.left, mn=mn, mx=root.val):
    return False
  if root.right and not isValidBST(root.right, mn=root.val, mx=mx):
    return False
  return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct.

An improvement could be the following:

```
def isValidBST(root: Node, mn=float('-Inf'), mx=float('+Inf')) -> bool:
  if not root:
    return True
  if mn < root.val < mx:
    return isValidBST(root.left, mn=mn, mx=root.val) and isValidBST(root.right, mn=root.val, mx=mx)
  return False
```

At least the empty tree is now tackled (and is a valid BST), and the property is much clearly expressed (IMHO).